# Let $w \in G_{63}$ be a primitive root of unity. Find all $n\geq 6$ such that $\sum_{k=6}^n w^{35k} = 0$ and $w^{12n} = w^{15}$

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

**This is probably totally wrong.**

We know that $5$ and $63$ are relatively prime, therefore $w^5 \in G_{63}$ primitive (we'll suppose $w= w^5$ without loss of generality).

We also know that $(w^7)^9 = w^{63} = 1$, so $w^7 \in G_9$.

If $w^7$ were primitive **(is it?, how do I prove this?)**, then

$$\sum_{k=6}^n w^{35k} = \sum_{k=6}^n (w^7)^k = 0 \ \iff \ n \equiv 5 \pmod 9$$

Because we need the sum of terms $\{6,7,\dots,n\}$ to span a complete set of residues (modulo $9$) a fixed number of times.

On the other hand,

$$w^{12n} = w^{15} \ \iff \ (w^3)^{4n} = (w^3)^5 \ \iff \ n \equiv 17 \pmod {21}$$

**So the final answer is $n \equiv 59 \pmod {63}$?**

Comment: $w^7$ is, obviously, not primitive in $G_{63}$ (since it belongs to $G_9$). On the other hand, for integers $k$, $(w^7)^k=1$ iff $w^{7k}=1$, iff $63|7k$, iff $9|k$, thus $w^7$ is primitive in $G_9$.

Comment: The proof itself is almost correct, but for the weird $”w=w^5”$ part. Just write $w’=w^5$, it is also a generator of $G_{63}$ and ...

Comment: @Mindlack I'm very anal about diacritics (my background is in graphic design) and $(w' ^7)^9$ looks ugly and confusing. I also have this problem with the subindices of subsequences.

Comment: I can see your point. So instead of naming it $w’$, name it $v$, $z$, or $u$ for instance. However, note that there are situations (derivatives) where this is (to my knowledge) the widely-used notation.